# 'dotnet quit unexpectedly' after installing hangfire

Tags: .net, asp.net-core

I installed HangFire packages and made several changes in Startup.cs
After building the code, I get this error: "dotnet quit unexpectedly".

Startup.cs

```
 public void ConfigureServices (IServiceCollection services) {


        services.AddHangfire(configuration=>{
            configuration.UseSqlServerStorage("ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection");
        });


        services.AddMvc();
        // Add framework services.
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure (IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env) {

        app.UseHangfireServer();
        app.UseHangfireDashboard();    



    }
```

Problem is with 2 lines in Configure(). 
app.UseHangFireServer() and app.UseHangfireDashboard();
When I remove these two, it runs fine.

I tried:
deleting nuget cache and restore.
checked dotnet --version in terminal and in project and they both are the same(2.2.106)

UPDATE:
I fixed the part where I had trouble building the code. The problem was that I was using UseSqlServerStorage instead of UsePostgreSqlServerStorage.

I have another problem now: I can not access dashboard. http://localhost:5000/hangfire page doesn't exist.

Comment: Which command is failing? `dotnet build` or `dotnet run`?

Comment: @HenkMollema dotnet run is failing

Comment: Then the problem might be that initializing Hangfire fails, such as connecting to the database. Are you sure the connection string `ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection` is present in the config and that the database can be accessed from your app?

Comment: @HenkMollema Yes. I use it as default connectionstring.  like this : var connectionString = Configuration["ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection"];
            services.AddEntityFrameworkNpgsql ()
                .AddDbContext<EntityContext> (
                    options => options.UseNpgsql (connectionString)
                );

Comment: According to `UseNpgsql` it looks like you're using PostgreSQL while you're configuring Hangfire to use SQL Server (`UseSqlServerStorage`) with the same connection string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seems to be an error when initializing Hangfire which crashes the startup of your application. This can be because of an incorrect connection string, inaccessible database or incompatible database system. It looks like you're using PostgreSQL while you're configuring Hangfire to use SQL Server.

You might want to look into this package which contains a Hangfire implementation for PostgreSQL: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Hangfire.PostgreSql/.

Comment: I installed postgreSQL package(the one from the link you provided). and modified my configure services to this : services.AddHangfire(configuration=>{
                configuration.UsePostgreSqlStorage("ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection");
            });
            
still didn't work

Comment: I added this in UsePostgreSqlStorage() : Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")
Now dotnet run works. Problem is that I can not access hangfire dashboard, can it be connected to this problem?

Comment: What happens when you access the dashboard? Keep in mind that it can only be accessed using local connections by default.

Comment: When I try to access http://localhost:5000/hangfire it says, that the page doesn't exist.

Comment: Depending on your routes, maybe: *localhost:5000/api/hangfire* ? Alternatively you can define the desired path for hangfire in *app.UseHangfireDashboard("/dashboard")*

Comment: @RoelAbspoel still does the same. Should anyone be allowed this route? I was logged in with my user when I tried to access it.

Comment: @GugaTodua by default Hangfire allows connections from the same host. You can make this more or less restrictive by creating an authorization filter and adding it into the options of UseHangfireDashboard. If your Configure method has more lines than the ones you posted, try moving the Hangfire inits higher up.

Comment: @GugaTodua Also: Since Henk answered your origional question, accept his answer and maybe start a new question for this new problem? :)

Comment: fixed it. hangfire could not create a schema in database because I had to give it manually from server

Answer (score 0):

got the same error because I missed a connection string of the second database